error: cannot repair to "manylinux_2_28_x86_64" ABI because of the presence of too-recent versioned symbols
I am trying to build my python package inside a manylinux_2_28 container but I am getting the error:
error: cannot repair "pynemo-0.0.0.dev0-cp311-cp311-linux_x86_64.whl" to "manylinux_2_28_x86_64" ABI because of the presence of too-recent versioned symbols. 

Using auditwheel-symbols I am getting:
pynemo/_core.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so is manylinux_2_28 compliant.
pynemo/ld-2.28.so is manylinux_2_28 compliant.
pynemo/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 is manylinux_2_28 compliant.
pynemo/libc-2.28.so is manylinux_2_28 compliant.
pynemo/libc.so.6 is manylinux_2_28 compliant.
pynemo/libdl-2.28.so is not manylinux_2_28 compliant because it links the following forbidden libraries:
libc.so.6       offending symbols: _dl_signal_error@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, _dl_vsym@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, _dl_addr@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, _dl_sym@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, _dl_rtld_di_serinfo@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
pynemo/libdl.so.2 is not manylinux_2_28 compliant because it links the following forbidden libraries:
libc.so.6       offending symbols: _dl_signal_error@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, _dl_vsym@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, _dl_addr@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, _dl_sym@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, _dl_rtld_di_serinfo@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
pynemo/libgcc_s-8-20210514.so.1 is manylinux_2_28 compliant.
pynemo/libgcc_s.so.1 is manylinux_2_28 compliant.
pynemo/libm-2.28.so is not manylinux_2_28 compliant because it links the following forbidden libraries:
libc.so.6       offending versions: GLIBC_PRIVATE
pynemo/libm.so.6 is not manylinux_2_28 compliant because it links the following forbidden libraries:
libc.so.6       offending versions: GLIBC_PRIVATE
pynemo/libpthread-2.28.so is not manylinux_2_28 compliant because it links the following forbidden libraries:
libc.so.6       offending symbols: __libc_siglongjmp@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __tsearch@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __getrlimit@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_dlclose@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_fatal@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __sigtimedwait@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __mmap@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_system@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __munmap@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_fork@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, _IO_enable_locks@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __write_nocancel@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, _dl_deallocate_tls@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __call_tls_dtors@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_thread_freeres@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __mprotect@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __clock_gettime@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_fcntl64@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __nanosleep_nocancel@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_current_sigrtmax_private@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __tdelete@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_dlopen_mode@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __read_nocancel@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, _dl_make_stack_executable@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_pthread_init@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __ctype_init@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_dlsym@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __tfind@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __open64_nocancel@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_current_sigrtmin_private@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __madvise@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __pause_nocancel@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __mktemp@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __twalk@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, _dl_allocate_tls@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __tunable_get_val@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, _dl_get_tls_static_info@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_alloca_cutoff@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, _dl_allocate_tls_init@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __close_nocancel@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_allocate_rtsig_private@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_longjmp@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
pynemo/libpthread.so.0 is not manylinux_2_28 compliant because it links the following forbidden libraries:
libc.so.6       offending symbols: __libc_siglongjmp@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __tsearch@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __getrlimit@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_dlclose@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_fatal@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __sigtimedwait@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __mmap@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_system@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __munmap@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_fork@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, _IO_enable_locks@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __write_nocancel@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, _dl_deallocate_tls@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __call_tls_dtors@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_thread_freeres@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __mprotect@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __clock_gettime@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_fcntl64@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __nanosleep_nocancel@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_current_sigrtmax_private@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __tdelete@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_dlopen_mode@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __read_nocancel@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, _dl_make_stack_executable@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_pthread_init@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __ctype_init@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_dlsym@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __tfind@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __open64_nocancel@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_current_sigrtmin_private@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __madvise@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __pause_nocancel@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __mktemp@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __twalk@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, _dl_allocate_tls@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __tunable_get_val@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, _dl_get_tls_static_info@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_alloca_cutoff@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, _dl_allocate_tls_init@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __close_nocancel@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_allocate_rtsig_private@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_longjmp@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
pynemo/librt-2.28.so is not manylinux_2_28 compliant because it links the following forbidden libraries:
libc.so.6       offending symbols: __recv@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_pwrite@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_fatal@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_pread@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __pthread_barrier_init@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __pthread_unwind@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __pthread_get_minstack@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_dlopen_mode@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __pthread_barrier_wait@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_dlsym@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __socket@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __pthread_attr_copy@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __shm_directory@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __fortify_fail@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __close_nocancel@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
libpthread.so.0 offending symbols: __recv@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_pwrite@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_fatal@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_pread@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __pthread_barrier_init@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __pthread_unwind@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __pthread_get_minstack@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_dlopen_mode@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __pthread_barrier_wait@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_dlsym@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __socket@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __pthread_attr_copy@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __shm_directory@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __fortify_fail@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __close_nocancel@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
pynemo/librt.so.1 is not manylinux_2_28 compliant because it links the following forbidden libraries:
libpthread.so.0 offending symbols: __recv@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_pwrite@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_fatal@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_pread@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __pthread_barrier_init@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __pthread_unwind@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __pthread_get_minstack@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_dlopen_mode@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __pthread_barrier_wait@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_dlsym@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __socket@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __pthread_attr_copy@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __shm_directory@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __fortify_fail@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __close_nocancel@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
libc.so.6       offending symbols: __recv@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_pwrite@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_fatal@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_pread@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __pthread_barrier_init@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __pthread_unwind@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __pthread_get_minstack@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_dlopen_mode@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __pthread_barrier_wait@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __libc_dlsym@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __socket@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __pthread_attr_copy@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __shm_directory@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __fortify_fail@@GLIBC_PRIVATE, __close_nocancel@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
pynemo/libstdc++.so.6 is manylinux_2_28 compliant.
pynemo/libstdc++.so.6.0.25 is manylinux_2_28 compliant.

So it seems like my wheel is getting multiple versions of libstdc++, libc and libpthread but I am not sure why this is happening as I am building the entire wheel from inside the container.
Looking in the logs, it seems like all of the lib files it needs are taken from the /lib64 folder in the container:
DEBUG:auditwheel.wheel_abi:full_elftree:
{
    "pynemo/_core.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so": {
        "interp": null,
        "path": "pynemo/_core.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so",
        "realpath": "pynemo/_core.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so",
        "needed": [
            "libpthread.so.0",
            "librt.so.1",
            "libdl.so.2",
            "libstdc++.so.6",
            "libm.so.6",
            "libgcc_s.so.1",
            "libc.so.6",
            "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"
        ],
        "rpath": [],
        "runpath": [],
        "libs": {
            "libpthread.so.0": {
                "realpath": "/lib64/libpthread-2.28.so",
                "path": "/lib64/libpthread.so.0",
                "needed": [
                    "libc.so.6",
                    "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"
                ]
            },
            "libc.so.6": {
                "realpath": "/lib64/libc-2.28.so",
                "path": "/lib64/libc.so.6",
                "needed": [
                    "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"
                ]
            },
            "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2": {
                "realpath": "/lib64/ld-2.28.so",
                "path": "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2",
                "needed": []
            },
            "librt.so.1": {
                "realpath": "/lib64/librt-2.28.so",
                "path": "/lib64/librt.so.1",
                "needed": [
                    "libpthread.so.0",
                    "libc.so.6"
                ]
            },
            "libdl.so.2": {
                "realpath": "/lib64/libdl-2.28.so",
                "path": "/lib64/libdl.so.2",
                "needed": [
                    "libc.so.6",
                    "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"
                ]
            },
            "libstdc++.so.6": {
                "realpath": "/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.25",
                "path": "/lib64/libstdc++.so.6",
                "needed": [
                    "libm.so.6",
                    "libc.so.6",
                    "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2",
                    "libgcc_s.so.1"
                ]
            },
            "libm.so.6": {
                "realpath": "/lib64/libm-2.28.so",
                "path": "/lib64/libm.so.6",
                "needed": [
                    "libc.so.6",
                    "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"
                ]
            },
            "libgcc_s.so.1": {
                "realpath": "/lib64/libgcc_s-8-20210514.so.1",
                "path": "/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1",
                "needed": [
                    "libc.so.6"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "pynemo/ld-2.28.so": {
        "interp": null,
        "path": "pynemo/ld-2.28.so",
        "realpath": "pynemo/ld-2.28.so",
        "needed": [],
        "rpath": [],
        "runpath": [],
        "libs": {}
    },
    "pynemo/libc-2.28.so": {
        "interp": "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2",
        "path": "pynemo/libc-2.28.so",
        "realpath": "pynemo/libc-2.28.so",
        "needed": [
            "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"
        ],
        "rpath": [],
        "runpath": [],
        "libs": {
            "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2": {
                "path": "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2",
                "realpath": "/lib64/ld-2.28.so",
                "needed": []
            }
        }
    },
    "pynemo/libdl-2.28.so": {
        "interp": null,
        "path": "pynemo/libdl-2.28.so",
        "realpath": "pynemo/libdl-2.28.so",
        "needed": [
            "libc.so.6",
            "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"
        ],
        "rpath": [],
        "runpath": [],
        "libs": {
            "libc.so.6": {
                "realpath": "/lib64/libc-2.28.so",
                "path": "/lib64/libc.so.6",
                "needed": [
                    "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"
                ]
            },
            "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2": {
                "realpath": "/lib64/ld-2.28.so",
                "path": "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2",
                "needed": []
            }
        }
    },
    "pynemo/libgcc_s-8-20210514.so.1": {
        "interp": null,
        "path": "pynemo/libgcc_s-8-20210514.so.1",
        "realpath": "pynemo/libgcc_s-8-20210514.so.1",
        "needed": [
            "libc.so.6"
        ],
        "rpath": [],
        "runpath": [],
        "libs": {
            "libc.so.6": {
                "realpath": "/lib64/libc-2.28.so",
                "path": "/lib64/libc.so.6",
                "needed": [
                    "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"
                ]
            },
            "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2": {
                "realpath": "/lib64/ld-2.28.so",
                "path": "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2",
                "needed": []
            }
        }
    },
    "pynemo/libm-2.28.so": {
        "interp": null,
        "path": "pynemo/libm-2.28.so",
        "realpath": "pynemo/libm-2.28.so",
        "needed": [
            "libc.so.6",
            "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"
        ],
        "rpath": [],
        "runpath": [],
        "libs": {
            "libc.so.6": {
                "realpath": "/lib64/libc-2.28.so",
                "path": "/lib64/libc.so.6",
                "needed": [
                    "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"
                ]
            },
            "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2": {
                "realpath": "/lib64/ld-2.28.so",
                "path": "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2",
                "needed": []
            }
        }
    },
    "pynemo/libpthread-2.28.so": {
        "interp": "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2",
        "path": "pynemo/libpthread-2.28.so",
        "realpath": "pynemo/libpthread-2.28.so",
        "needed": [
            "libc.so.6",
            "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"
        ],
        "rpath": [],
        "runpath": [],
        "libs": {
            "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2": {
                "path": "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2",
                "realpath": "/lib64/ld-2.28.so",
                "needed": []
            },
            "libc.so.6": {
                "realpath": "/lib64/libc-2.28.so",
                "path": "/lib64/libc.so.6",
                "needed": [
                    "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "pynemo/librt-2.28.so": {
        "interp": null,
        "path": "pynemo/librt-2.28.so",
        "realpath": "pynemo/librt-2.28.so",
        "needed": [
            "libpthread.so.0",
            "libc.so.6"
        ],
        "rpath": [],
        "runpath": [],
        "libs": {
            "libpthread.so.0": {
                "realpath": "/lib64/libpthread-2.28.so",
                "path": "/lib64/libpthread.so.0",
                "needed": [
                    "libc.so.6",
                    "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"
                ]
            },
            "libc.so.6": {
                "realpath": "/lib64/libc-2.28.so",
                "path": "/lib64/libc.so.6",
                "needed": [
                    "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"
                ]
            },
            "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2": {
                "realpath": "/lib64/ld-2.28.so",
                "path": "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2",
                "needed": []
            }
        }
    },
    "pynemo/libstdc++.so.6.0.25": {
        "interp": null,
        "path": "pynemo/libstdc++.so.6.0.25",
        "realpath": "pynemo/libstdc++.so.6.0.25",
        "needed": [
            "libm.so.6",
            "libc.so.6",
            "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2",
            "libgcc_s.so.1"
        ],
        "rpath": [],
        "runpath": [],
        "libs": {
            "libm.so.6": {
                "realpath": "/lib64/libm-2.28.so",
                "path": "/lib64/libm.so.6",
                "needed": [
                    "libc.so.6",
                    "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"
                ]
            },
            "libc.so.6": {
                "realpath": "/lib64/libc-2.28.so",
                "path": "/lib64/libc.so.6",
                "needed": [
                    "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"
                ]
            },
            "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2": {
                "realpath": "/lib64/ld-2.28.so",
                "path": "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2",
                "needed": []
            },
            "libgcc_s.so.1": {
                "realpath": "/lib64/libgcc_s-8-20210514.so.1",
                "path": "/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1",
                "needed": [
                    "libc.so.6"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}

Which are included in the container by default, so I am not sure why this is not compliant with auditwheel.
The script I am running before building my wheel is:
yum -y install curl zip unzip tar autoconf automake libtool pkg-config perl-open python3.11-pip
python3.11 -m pip install jinja2
for python in /opt/python/*/bin/python3*; do
    if [ -x "$python" ]; then
        echo "Using Python: $python"
        $python -m pip install jinja2
    fi
done
ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.11 /usr/bin/python3
git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg.git
./vcpkg/bootstrap-vcpkg.sh
./vcpkg/vcpkg install

So I am installing some system packages and installing some things from vcpkg. From what I can tell, vcpkg always compiles the packages on the machine so those should be okay, I am not sure about the installed system packages (curl zip unzip tar autoconf automake libtool pkg-config perl-open).
Is there any way I can fix the .so's that the wheel is looking for?
